# Open URL In java

Tags: java, download

How to open URL in java?

```
E.g i have https://www.iformbuilder.com/exzact/dataExcelFeed.php?
PAGE_ID=3175952&TABLE_NAME=_data399173_eff_sor&ANALYTIC=1&SINCE_DATE=2013-10-1
```

when we go to this URL it will download the file.But how to implement this thing in code?

I try this to open url so that file will be downloaded.But its not working.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.iformbuilder.com/exzact/dataExcelFeed.php?PAGE_ID=3175952&TABLE_NAME=_data399173_eff_sor&ANALYTIC=1&SINCE_DATE=2013-10-16");
    HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(urlCon);
    urlCon.connect();
```

I know something is wrong But i dont knw whats dat

Comment: I would suggest adding to the question things you've tried already.  Did it not work the way you tried it?  If you just want to know how to open and read a URL using Java, a Google search would help. Here's the first link that's returned when you query "URL java read" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

I have found this:

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.asp");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

In this article: [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

class HttpHelperx
{
   public static String GET(String url)
   {
      String result = "";

      try 
      {
         URL navUrl = new URL(url);
         URLConnection con = (URLConnection)navUrl.openConnection();

         result = getContent(con);

      } 
      catch (MalformedURLException e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return result;
   }

   public static String getContent(URLConnection con)
   {
      String result = "";
      if(con!=null)
      {
         BufferedReader br;
         try 
         {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String aux = "";

            while ((aux = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
               buffer.append(aux);
            }
            result = buffer.toString();
            br.close();
         } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      return result;
   }
}
```

To use it:

```
public class HTTPHelperDriver
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
      throws Exception
   {
      String response = HttpHelperx.GET("http://www.google.com");
      System.out.println(response); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
try {
    //specify the protocol along with the URL
    URI oURL = new URI("https://www.google.com/");
    desktop.browse(oURL);
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```